# Android app crashes with DeadObjectException when showing progress dialog

Tags: android

My android app has crashed with following exception in a certain device running Android 8.0.

Crash occurs when the app tries to show a progress dialog.

Only this particular device has this problem. In other devices, progress dialog works fine.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4179)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4219)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3314)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1891)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:857)
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:372)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:128)
  at android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:454)
  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show (ProgressDialog.java:185)
  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show (ProgressDialog.java:142)
  at com.my.app.MainActivity.downloadInitialData (MainActivity.java:1132)
  at com.my.app.MainActivity.onPostResume (MainActivity.java:285)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:7505)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4147)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: 
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native Method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:751)
  at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay (IWindowSession.java:791)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:845)
```

Following is the line where I show the progress dialog which has caused the crash.

```
ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.loading), getString(R.string.please_wait), true);
```

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this crash?

Comment: @Lahiry Chandima please add some code to let us help you! Please click the link to the activity that causes error and paste that specific code on the question!

Comment: @Gourav added the statement which has caused the crash

Comment: Please use "try { ProgressDialog.show(..); } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage()); }" to show the error message. There are more than 2 RuntimeException inside "performResumeActivity()" method and if the Message is not written in the log, I think you should print it out.

Comment: @emandt Unfortunately this does not re-create in my test device. This is a user reported crash which I received through Google Play.